# Netatalk and Snow Leopard Slow transfer speed

Tags: networking, mac-osx, afp, netatalk

I have a simple setup of netatalk afp server on my OpenSolaris box. And I also have samba on that box.

transfers from netatalk to my mac mini with Snow Leopard 10.6.8 go at speed 2-3 Mbytes/sec

but transfers from the same server using samba peak at 8-12 Mbytes/sec

Why do i have this huge difference? Am I missing something regarding afp config?

My afpd.conf looks like this

```
- -setuplog "afpdaemon log_info /var/log/afpd.log" -noddp -uamlist uams_dhx.so -nosavepassword
```

And this is my AppleVolumes.default

```
~ cnidscheme:dbd options:usedots,invisibledots,upriv perm:0770
```

netatalk is compiled using gcc 4.3.2
I don't have any tcp/ip tunes applied to my system it's just standart OpenSolaris 2009.06

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, anything interesting in the logs while this is going on? I get 25-60MBps over 1 gigE between my MBP17 and our Linux AFP backup host (raid1 of the built in disks, next step, add storage) depending on sending or receiving, doing Time Machine backups and restores.

Not done much with solaris in some time, also, netatalk version? The netatalk people have some good mailing lists, I'm running the current Netatalk beta, and it works great, and makes things much easier.